# jQuery: I need a custom hide() for toggling menu

Tags: jquery

I have a simple menu/submenu with jquery click() function and toggle().
My problem is, toggle() is working fine, but when for e.g. #submenu1 is open, and I click on "Menu 2", #submenu1 remains visible of course, and both submenus overlap.
So I need a hide() for the submenus, but I don't get it work! I tried not(), siblings() with no success. Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

jQuery:

```
$('#menu li').click(function() {
$('div', this).stop(true, true).animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 300);
 });
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
       <div id="submenu1">
           <ul>
              <li>Submenu 1</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
       <div id="submenu2">
           <ul>
              <li>Submenu 2</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#submenu1, #submenu2 {
z-index: 99;
position: absolute;
background: #6fb700;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: http://jsfiddle.net/D9pq8/

```
$('#menu li').click(function () {
   $(this).siblings().children('div').hide();
   $('div', this).stop(true, true).animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**Edit To shorten version**

```
$("#menu li").click(function() {
    if($('div' , this).css('display') != 'block')
            $("#menu li div.active").hide().removeClass('active');

      $('div', this).addClass('active').stop(true, true).animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 300);  
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/axKrJ/1/)

[This is your fiddel example](http://jsfiddle.net/eLPCF/5/)

Comment: I tried this before, it doesn't work. Switching from one menu to another works with this, but toggling the same menu does not work anymore (because of first hiding itself).

Comment: thank, that's what I need :) .. any chance to get a shorter version of this?

Comment: Updated to shorten version

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this with jquery tabs. Main menus in vertucal mode and submenus in default mode
EX: [Tabs UI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Answer (score 0):

Extending on what @silagy posted:

```
 $('#menu li').click(function() {
     $("#menu li div.active").hide().removeClass('active');
    $('div', this).addClass('active').stop(true, true).animate({ 'height': 'toggle' }, 300);
});
```

This simply adds an 'active' class so there is no double animating a menu item.

Comment: sorry it's the same problem I mentioned above to silagy.